# Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Error

Tags: vb6, activex, reference, ado

I'm referencing the following dll in a VB6 dll I'm creating:

```
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library
```

After making the VB6 dll, it works fine, but on other people's computers, the following error pops up:

```
Run-time error '429'
ActiveX component can't create object
```

I'm pretty sure this is related to the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library.  Any idea how to fix this error?  I've tried replacing the ActiveX dll on other people's computers with mine, but that didn't work.  I tried putting my ActiveX dll on a shared drive and reference to that, but that didn't work.  I tried referencing the 2.7 library and that didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try on the client machine:

1. Download and reinstall [MDAC 2.8 (32-bit only)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=6c050fe3-c795-4b7d-b037-185d0506396c&displaylang=en).
2. Make sure `C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\MSADO15.dll` is properly registered by using `regsvr32`.
3. Make sure the client's user account has Read/Execute rights to the following folders: `C:\Program Files\Common Files\System` and `C:\WINNT` or `C:\Windows`.
4. Reboot.

As Beaner mentioned below, you would need also to download and install the drivers for FoxPro and Jet 4.0 separately, if you are using either one of those connection methods.

- [Download Jet 4.0 SP8](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=2DEDDEC4-350E-4CD0-A12A-D7F70A153156&displaylang=en)
- [Download Visual FoxPro ODBC Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vfoxpro/bb190233.aspx)

Comment: @Soo, you may also need to separately install Jet or FoxPro drivers depending on what you're using for your database

"... This release does not include Microsoft Jet, the Microsoft Jet OLE DB Provider or ODBC driver, the Desktop Database ODBC Drivers, or the Visual FoxPro ODBC Driver."

Comment: @Beaner - That is true, I forgot those were separate downloads.